# Emmet plugin in Sublime Text 2 with Soy Templates

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

Has anyone gotten the Emmet plugin to work with Soy Templates in Sublime Text 2? I tried following the recommendation here: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/
and added a syntaxProfiles.json file with the following:

{
    "SoyTemplate": "html"
}

but that didn't do anything.

Any advice would be tremendously appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t just write `{ "SoyTemplate": "html" }` and hope that Emmet will automagically know that you’re currently working with Soy Templates and it should just give you desired output.

In most cases, you can simply use `Ctrl+E` shortcut in all unknown (to Emmet) syntaxes to get HTML content.

To make it work with Tab key in Sublime Text, you have to do some rather complex things:

1. First, you have to tweak [syntax scopes in tab triggers](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Default%20%28OSX%29.sublime-keymap#L359) and supply them with Soy Template scopes. To get current scope name in editor’s status bar, press Ctrl+Shift+P (OSX) or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P (Windows).
2. Then you need to somehow modify [pyGetSyntax()](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/editor.js#L299) method and make sure it returns `SoyTemplate` name for your Soy Template syntax scope. The best way to do so is to override this method in [JS extension](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/).